# access sharepoint list from outside

Tags: 2010, web-services

I have developed a custom SharePoint 2010 webservice using the following link
http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2011/11/04/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-asp-net-asmx-web-service-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Inisde the web method I am taking couple of parameters and writing into a sharepoint 2010 list. This webservice will be consumed from Oracle EBS server which is on LINUX and wont be a part of our domain so when the Oracle EBS pass parameters to my web method and then it tries to write into sharepoint list it fails.

How to over come this problem. I cant use RunWithElevatedPreviliges cause i am using NINTEX workflow product which doesn't invoke workflow if writes through system account.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: vendor tried with a tool called SOAPUI ..they are getting client exception. their server is linux based..do they need some kinda of trusted relationship between our domain and their linux server.